# What happens to the initial voltage of resistor as soon switch changes?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics

For when the switch is at x for a long time , i've calculated that the 30 nF capacitor reaches a steady state OCing around 120V. So when it switches instantaneosly, how does it affect the resistor voltage? How to calculatee voltage of resistor (60kOhm)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At T0 after the switch, the 60nF will begin charging, as the initial charge on the capacitor is 0, it means its voltage will be based on the right hand side divider, this voltage will be divided between the 2 capacitors, with the 30nF charging the 60nF

The relationships I leave to you as this screams of homework.